# Automapper throw error when use Project().To<> in many to many relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, automapper

I got this error

> Unable to create a null constant value of type
>   'EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile'. Only entity types, enumeration types or
>   primitive types are supported in this context.

and these tables work fine with Mapper.create<>,  but if 
I change it to use `Project().To<ViewModels.Profile>()` it's throw me above error. Detail is as follow, I did something wrong?

**POCO**

```
public  class Cust_ProfileTbl
{
    [Key]
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; } 
    public string nvarCardName { get; set; }
    public string varEmail { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl> profileFamilyParents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl> profileFamilyChildren { get; set; }
}

public class Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl
{
    [Key]
    public int intProfileFamily { get; set; } 
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    public long bintAccountNoMember { get; set; }

    public virtual Cust_ProfileTbl custProfileParent { get; set; }
    public virtual Cust_ProfileTbl custProfileChild { get; set; }
}
```

**In onModelCreating**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl>()
       .HasRequired(m => m.custProfileParent)
       .WithMany(t => t.profileFamilyParents)
       .HasForeignKey(m => m.bintAccountNo)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.custProfileChild)
            .WithMany(t => t.profileFamilyChildren)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.bintAccountNoMember)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class Profile  
{

    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    public string varCardNo { get; set; }
    public string nvarCardName { get; set; }

    public string varEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProfileFamily> profileFamilyParents { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<ProfileFamily> profileFamilyChildren { get; set; }
    public Profile()
    {
        //profileFamilyParents = new Collection<ProfileFamily>();
        profileFamilyChildren = new Collection<ProfileFamily>();
    }


}

public class ProfileFamily 
{
    public int intProfileFamily { get; set; }
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    public long bintAccountNoMember { get; set; }

   //public Profile custProfileParent { get; set; }
    public ProfileChild custProfileParent { get; set; }

}

 //New class 
 public class ProfileChild
{

    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    public string varCardNo { get; set; }
    public string nvarCardName { get; set; }
    public string varEmail { get; set; }
}
```

**LINQ and AutoMapper**

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Cust_ProfileTbl, bool>> wherep = (x) => x.bintAccountNo==1;

EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile customerViewItem2 = context.member
    .Include("profileFamilyParents.custProfileChild")
    .Where(wherep)
    .Project()
    .To<ViewModels.Profile>()
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

**Global.asax**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>(); 
Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.ProfileChild>(); 
Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.ProfileFamily>();
```

Comment: There is something I did understand in the wrong way about Project().To(), so I deleted my answer. Please, tell me what is `context.member` in your last block of code.

Comment: What happens if you remove `varCardNo` and `profileFamilyChildren ` in the `Profile` view model? Have you tested projecting to a Profile class and adding the properties one by one to find the offending one?

Comment: I tried 1 to many , many to many, and 1 to 1. So far only 1 to many is fine. From my example, if i remove profilFamilyParent and profilFamilyChildren  then is fine.

Comment: Your comment is really confusing profilFamilyParent/CHildre are both collections, so they're 1 to many, and you say 1 to many is fine. Why don't you post the code of specific thigns that work or fail?

Comment: Sorry, just ignore the rest focus on many to many relationship. This question is on many to many relationship. I just want to let you know i tried other relationship on different tables but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve it by removing this line from LINQ, i don't know why but i'm just luckily remove it and everything work, Weird. :)

```
.Include("profileFamilyParents.custProfileChild")
```

Comment: You don't need Include, since AutoMapper generates a Select projection. LINQ providers use the projection to determine what to "Include", so it's unnecessary. Additionally, Include doesn't work against custom projections, AutoMapper or not.

Comment: OK, now i get it. The output/fields/select Projection is actually control by my ViewModels, but still is kind of weird on error raise, as when i use "Include" in LINQ on 1 to 1 tables or 1 to Many tables it doesn't complain. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have recursive view models here. Since EF/LINQ can't do recursive joins (it would need to generate CTEs), you need to limit the depth to a reasonable number:

```
CreateMap<Cust_ProfileTbl, ViewModels.Profile>().MaxDepth(2);
```

Remember, AutoMapper just builds a Select projection based on examining source/destination types. If your destination types have circular references, when should it stop? Ideally, you'd break this into two queries - SQL is a horrible abstraction for building complex graphs.

I'd create two queries, one for the one Profile, then another for the ProfileFamily.

Alternatively, you can create a separate ChildProfile class in your ViewModel that *does not* have any ProfileFamily collection properties, removing any circular references.

Comment: 1st approach not working :(. 2nd approach hmm.. i think work ... hmmm.. thanks for suggestion will try that. Prefer not have more classes :).

Comment: Updated code as above. i tried 2nd approach and confirm the circular references is removed but still getting error "Unable to create a null constant value of type 'EFWeb.ViewModels.ProfileChild'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.". Just curious, why using Mapper.Create<> is able to map but with QueryableExtensions.Project().To<> it will throw error. It happened when the table relationship is 1 to 1 as well.

Comment: One thing you can try is to replace the Project.To with LINQ Select. When I run into EF Queryable problems, hand-rolling the Select projection lets me fiddle with the Select expression, then I can figure out what's going on in AutoMapper (which merely builds a Select expression anyway).